# joint orientation (rotation)

Tags: ros, joint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

It looks like the joint rotation is given with the roll, pitch and yaw in this order:

http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint

And too bad, the document of the robot I'm working on is in the ypr order. And moreover, this last oder looks more common, as I found a lot of documentation based on this convention.

How to convert ypr to rpy?

Why has it been changed for ROS? Am I the only one to be disturbed by this?

Thanks in advance for the support.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84601/joint-orientation-(rotation)/) by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2013-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Is your documentation using a fixed axis or rotating axis (extrinsic or intrinsic rotation?)**

The URDF documentation is using a **fixed axis** rotation. This is described in more detail here: [REP 103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html#rotation-representation)

Also, here: [Rotation Methods (ROS)](http://wiki.ros.org/geometry/RotationMethods#Fixed_Axis_vs_Euler_Angles)

If your documentation is using rotating axis (intrinsic rotation) there is no problem as `ypr` on a rotating axis is same as `rpy` on a fixed axis.

**Otherwise:**

The easiest way might to convert rotations between Euler angles is to use an intermediate representation like a quaternion.

In ROS if you are using Python, you can use the `transformations.py` module mentioned here (with a link to the full source): [transformations.py](http://wiki.ros.org/geometry/RotationMethods#transformations.py)

Example Python session using this (first way is with quaternions, second with matrices):

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jul  5 2013, 08:52:38) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import transformations
>>> import math
>>> q=transformations.quaternion_from_euler(math.pi,0,0,'szyx')
>>> q
array([  0.00000000e+00,  -0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
        6.12303177e-17])
>>> transformations.euler_from_quaternion(q,'sxyz')
(0.0, -0.0, 3.141592653589793)
>>> m=transformations.euler_matrix(math.pi,0,0,'szyx')
>>> m
array([[ -1.00000000e+00,  -1.22460635e-16,  -0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00],
    [  1.22460635e-16,  -1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00],
    [ -0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00],
    [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
        1.00000000e+00]])
>>> transformations.euler_from_matrix(m,'sxyz')
(0.0, 0.0, 3.141592653589793)
```

---

Originally posted by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) with karma: 399 on 2013-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) on 2013-09-29**:
Note that fixed axis rotation can mean in general about any axis, but in the ROS documentation I linked to it is referring to 3 rotations around fixed axes x y and z ('sxyz' in transformations.py). This should be the same as 'rzyx' in transformations.py).